# Excel VBA GoalSeek by each row in a table

Tags: excel, vba, loops, seek

I am looking to perform a goal seek within each row of a specified table. The following VBA code successfully executes the GoalSeek.

```
Sub GoalSeek()
 Dim lo As ListObject
 Dim rw
 Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")

 For rw = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
  Range("M" & rw).GoalSeek Goal:=Range("N" & rw).Value, ChangingCell:=Range("E" & rw)
 Next
End Sub
```

It fails to execute all the way through and generates run-time error 1004: GoalSeek method of Range class failed

[image]
f

Any suggestions on how to resolve? I have attached a copy of the workbook below.

[Excel file copy](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmcGUE_vrclQ8EKncl_Ys5Gsu5F7?e=jgugfU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you have reach the first row and it is not possible to GoalSeek that row.  so change this line of code

```
For rw = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1  
to =>  
For rw = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
```

Comment: Has anyone told you they appreciate you today? @Xshen. That worked. THANK YOU!